# SQL Query on reverting data from DE based on a filter condition and modify it before i put it into another DE

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio

I am trying to retrieve multiple Columns from a DE and split a column into multiple columns and insert into another DE along with the original column.

Ex : I have a DE-1 with Full name, Email and Phone Number as columns. 
I need to split the Full Name into 2 as First name and Last Name and Store it in a DE-2 along with Full name, Email and Phone Number.

How do i do this using an automation studio and SQL query in SFMC.

Answer (score 2):

You basically need to find where a space is in the `full name` and write whatever is before the space into the `first name` column and whatever is after the space to the `last name` column. This should do the trick:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING([full name], 1, CHARINDEX(' ', [full name]) - 1) AS Firstname,     
       SUBSTRING([full name],
                 CHARINDEX(' ', [full name]) + 1,
                 LEN([full name]) - CHARINDEX(' ', [full name])) AS Lastname
FROM de1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer you would like to use the same SQL functions

```
 SELECT EmailAddress,
      SUBSTRING(Fullname, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', FullName) - 1) AS FirstName,
      SUBSTRING(FullName, CHARINDEX(' ', FullName) + 1, 8000) AS LastName
    FROM [Your Data Extension Name]
```

When you will select the data extension in the next step it will automatically use the FirstName and Last name as target columns.

NOTE: It's considering your First name is separated by space